# Count search results in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

I'm new to Lucene and want to count occurences of a search word in an index.
I saw that I should use something like:

```
 IndexReader reader = .......
```

TermDocs termDoc = reader.TermDocs();

termDoc.Seek(new Term("my_field", mstrSearchFor));

int occurenceCount = termDoc.Freq();

I can't seem to create the IndexReader to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp\\"));
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
```

Comment: I'm running this code but the count stays 0 (it should be 10)..:


 Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\LuceneIndex\\"), false);
                            

 IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(dir);

TermDocs termDoc = reader.TermDocs();


termDoc.Seek(new Term("my_field", "strategy")); 

 termDoc.SkipTo(i);
                   
             
int occurenceCount = termDoc.Freq();

Comment: @viasualDna, why the call to SkipTo?